# START_STICKY cannot be resolved to a variable why?

Tags: android, variables

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){  
    if(!player.isPlaying()){  
        player.start();  
    }  
    return START_STICKY;  
}
```

ERROR is:
START_STICKY cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Is this written in any particular language?

Comment: What is `START_STICKY`, where is it declared, is it accessible in the current scope ? And I assume the language is Java. Please tag as such if it is or any other particular language.

Comment: I see Fred figured it out - I'll retag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you extending a Service or Activity?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: yes! of course.   Problems have been solved.thank you,my friend!